# Detect Click in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a list of product contained in a NSMutableDictionnary and I diplsay it like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvNGY.jpg

Now, I want to add a view for each products. If i click the "Basilic" for exemple I want to switch the view and have a new view, the products details or something else ..

I add this code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionAroma = [tableData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
NSString *aromaLabel = [sectionAroma objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = aromaLabel;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.textLabel.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.textLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
return cell;
}


-(void)buttonPressed :(id) sender {
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
NSLog(@"Tag = %ld", (long)gesture.view.tag);
}
```

In the log I got the ID , but it's not unique, the id is just the row number of the products, Here Armoise will be 0, Arbre Thé 1, but Basilic will be 0 and Baie will be 1 , etc ...
How can I create the view depending on the user's choice ?

Thank a lot for your help !

Comment: You just want a cell to be tappable ? There's a delegate method for that. tableView:didSelectRow:atIndexPath:

Comment: I want to redirect the user on the view that describe the products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UITableViewDelegate method

// Table view is Select a cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Your Code here 
}
```

Comment: So Thanks to that I will be able to show the view that describe the selected product ?

Comment: yes in this method you push your new viewcontroller. or You can hide unhide anotherview

Comment: And how am I supposed to know which product the user selects. For exemple, you click on the Basilic, and in me new view I want to display an image of the basilic and let's say the price, I don't want to create view for each products, I want it to be automatic. Is it possible ?

Comment: // Configure the cell...
NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionAroma = [tableData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
NSString *aromaLabel = [sectionAroma objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Do that in the method @BHASKAR showed you

Comment: in your tableview didselect you get the value buy this
[aromaSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did that : http://pastebin.com/NJQ79GZc 
Unfortunately the NSLog doesn't work is this normal ?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work , the log is empty, so the function is not called

Comment: Did you set your uitableview delegate?

Comment: Yes I Did : @interface SQLite_TUOViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

Comment: No This is not setting the delegate

Comment: yourtableviewname.delegate = (id)self; Or you can set from storyboard

Comment: Oh , sorry I'm new, how do I set the delegate so ?

Comment: i write the code in previous comment. yourtablename.delegate = (id)self;

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly, ;) Maybe just a last question, now that I got the name of the clicked label, How do I send this to the other view ?